# Running Kafka on Kubernetes with Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am unable to connect my local producer and consumer services (using KafkaJs) to connect to Kafka. I am using a load balancer service to expose my Kafka cluster to external clients. Sometimes I am able to connect to the Kafka cluster, but I will get error messages stating "This server is not the leader for that topic-partition", "This is not the correct controller for this cluster", and "Failed to send messages: This server does not host this topic-partition". I am very new to Kafka and microservices, so please be specific in your explanations.
Here is my code:

Kafka manifest

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: kafka-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: kafka-hs
  replicas: 3
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  updateStrategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: "app"
                      operator: In
                      values: 
                      - kafka
                topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      containers:
      - name: k8skafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-kafka:1.0-10.2.1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "3Gi"
            cpu: 2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9093
          name: server
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: client
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "exec kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties --override broker.id=${HOSTNAME##*-} \
          --override listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT \
          --override advertised.listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://${HOSTNAME}.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 \
          --override listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9092 \
          --override inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT \
          --override zookeeper.connect=zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 \
          --override log.dir=/var/lib/kafka \
          --override auto.create.topics.enable=true \
          --override auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true \
          --override background.threads=10 \
          --override compression.type=producer \
          --override delete.topic.enable=false \
          --override leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300 \
          --override leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10 \
          --override log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000 \
          --override log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.retention.bytes=-1 \
          --override log.retention.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.jitter.hours=0 \
          --override log.segment.bytes=1073741824 \
          --override log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000 \
          --override message.max.bytes=1000012 \
          --override min.insync.replicas=1 \
          --override num.io.threads=8 \
          --override num.network.threads=3 \
          --override num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1 \
          --override num.replica.fetchers=1 \
          --override offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096 \
          --override offsets.commit.required.acks=-1 \
          --override offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000 \
          --override offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880 \
          --override offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 \
          --override offsets.retention.minutes=1440 \
          --override offsets.topic.compression.codec=0 \
          --override offsets.topic.num.partitions=50 \
          --override offsets.topic.replication.factor=3 \
          --override offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600 \
          --override queued.max.requests=500 \
          --override quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override replica.fetch.min.bytes=1 \
          --override replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500 \
          --override replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000 \
          --override replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000 \
          --override replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536 \
          --override replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override request.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 \
          --override socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override unclean.leader.election.enable=true \
          --override zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override zookeeper.set.acl=false \
          --override broker.id.generation.enable=true \
          --override connections.max.idle.ms=600000 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.enable=true \
          --override controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000 \
          --override controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override default.replication.factor=1 \
          --override fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override group.max.session.timeout.ms=300000 \
          --override group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.2-IV0 \
          --override log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000 \
          --override log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728 \
          --override log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 \
          --override log.cleaner.enable=true \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0 \
          --override log.cleaner.threads=1 \
          --override log.cleanup.policy=delete \
          --override log.index.interval.bytes=4096 \
          --override log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime \
          --override log.preallocate=false \
          --override log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 \
          --override max.connections.per.ip=2147483647 \
          --override num.partitions=1 \
          --override producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576 \
          --override replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override reserved.broker.max.id=1000 "
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value : "-Xmx2G -Xms2G"
        - name: KAFKA_OPTS
          value: "-Dlogging.level=INFO"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
           command: 
            - sh 
            - -c 
            - "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9093"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-hs
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9093
    name: server
  selector:
    app: kafka

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-ds
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: client
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
```

-Zookeeper manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-hs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2888
    name: server
  - port: 3888
    name: leader-election
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-cs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    name: client
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: zk-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zk
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  serviceName: zk-hs
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zk
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: "app"
                      operator: In
                      values:
                      - zk
                topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-zookeeper
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "0.5"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: server
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader-election
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "start-zookeeper \
          --servers=3 \
          --data_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data \
          --data_log_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data/log \
          --conf_dir=/opt/zookeeper/conf \
          --client_port=2181 \
          --election_port=3888 \
          --server_port=2888 \
          --tick_time=2000 \
          --init_limit=10 \
          --sync_limit=5 \
          --heap=512M \
          --max_client_cnxns=60 \
          --snap_retain_count=3 \
          --purge_interval=12 \
          --max_session_timeout=40000 \
          --min_session_timeout=4000 \
          --log_level=INFO"
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

And here is my producer:

```
import { Kafka } from 'kafkajs';
const producer = async () => {
    const kafka = new Kafka({
            clientId: 'wedc-app',
        brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
        });
    const admin = kafka.admin();
    const producer = kafka.producer();
    try {
        await admin.connect();
        await producer.connect();
        try {
            await admin.createTopics({
                    waitForLeaders: true,
                    topics: [{ topic: 'user-created' }],
            });
            await producer.send({
                            acks: -1,
                            topic: 'user-created',
                            messages: [{ value: 'Testing' }],
                        });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Topic already exists');
            await producer.send({
                            acks: -1,
                            topic: 'user-created',
                            messages: [{ value: 'Testing' }],
                        });
        }
        await admin.disconnect();
        await producer.disconnect();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Something is wrong: ', e);
    }
    
}

producer();
```

Comment: Hi, we are getting same messages from tome to time as well, as far as I am aware of it does not indicate for an error and it is fixed on internal retry without any action needed from the client side

Comment: Last I heard, `google_containers/kubernetes-kafka` container or the "public" Kafka Helm Chart is not maintained and deprecated. I would suggest looking into https://strimzi.io for a simpler way to get a Kafka broker running. Ultimately, LoadBalancer is the wrong tool to connect to a Kafka Cluster... It already handles load-balancing _on its own_

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for the assistance. I ended up switching to NATS since my project is pretty small.